# Cannot install ghostscript, libgs9 and libpaper1 on Debian Bullseye

Tags: debian, apt, docker

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-bullseye


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install \
    --no-install-recommends -qq -y \
    apt-utils \
    poppler-utils \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    pdftk \
    ghostscript \
    autoconf-archive \
    pkg-config \
    libpng-dev \
    libtiff5-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    imagemagick \
    wget \
    procps \
    curl \
    locales \
    libicu-dev \
    libpango1.0-dev \
    g++ \
    make \
    tesseract-ocr \
    tesseract-ocr-por \
    tesseract-ocr-osd
```

I can build it through `sudo docker build -t foo .` on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04 and Docker version 19.03.10), but I can't do the same on Travis CI:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpaper1:amd64
 libgs9:amd64
 ghostscript
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install     --no-install-recommends -qq -y     apt-utils     poppler-utils     libjpeg-dev     libcairo2-dev     pdftk     ghostscript     autoconf-archive     pkg-config     libpng-dev     libtiff5-dev     zlib1g-dev     imagemagick     wget     procps     curl     locales     libicu-dev     libpango1.0-dev     g++     make     tesseract-ocr     tesseract-ocr-por     tesseract-ocr-osd     libc6     libgs9     ucf     libpaper1' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Part of log regarding libpaper1:

```
Setting up libpaper1:amd64 (1.1.28+b1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Creating config file /etc/papersize with new version
stat: cannot statx '/etc/papersize.dpkg-inst': Operation not permitted
dpkg: error processing package libpaper1:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpaper1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Part of log regarding libgs9:

```
dpkg: error processing package libgs9:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Part of log regarding ghostscript:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ghostscript:
 ghostscript depends on libgs9 (= 9.53.3~dfsg-7+deb11u1); however:
  Package libgs9:amd64 is not configured yet.
```

I tried the following without success:

```
RUN dpkg --configure -a && apt-get -f install
```

and also:

```
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install --fix-broken

RUN apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends -qq \
```

Part of my `.travis.yaml`:

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: Build temporary docker image
      services:
        - docker
      language: minimal
      if: type = pull_request AND branch = master
      script:
        - source ci_scripts/gcloud_setup.sh
        - gcloud docker -- pull gcr.io/foo/bar
        - docker build --cache-from gcr.io/foo/bar:latest -t bar_temp .
        - docker tag bar_temp gcr.io/foo/bar
        - gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/foo/bar
```

Am I missing something here? How can I install those packages without error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Root cause

In short the package `libpaper1`, as of today, is broken on some configuration steps with the default version of docker used on travis.

The issue with configuration step that fails on `libpaper1` install  comes from a `statx` and `libseccomp`.
On docker `statx` was whitelisted for `libseccomp` in docker 18.04.

https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36417

However this alone doesn't explain fully the issue, as of today `docker --version` on travis states `18.06.0-ce` which should have statx whitelisted but still has issues which I didn't find the reason.

Nevertheless, upgrading the docker image version solves the issue.

## Solution

Changing the docker version on travis solves the issue with `statx` which fix the installation of `libpaper1` and `ghostscript`.

In your `.travis.yml` file add the following:

```
# Need docker-ce 20 instead of docker-ce 18 for installing ghostscript/libpaper1 on debian:bullseye
# https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#installing-a-newer-docker-version
before_install:
   - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
   - sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
   - sudo apt-get update
   - sudo apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" install docker-ce
```

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#installing-a-newer-docker-version

Kudo to https://github.com/florentx for finding that out